# Estimating expected value with respect to posterior

Tags: bayesian, estimation, sampling, expected-value, posterior

I have a neural network and I need to calculate the following:
$$\mathbb{E}_{P(\theta|D)}[f(\theta)]=\frac{\sum_\theta P(D|\theta)P(\theta)f(\theta)}{\sum_\theta P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}$$
Where $f$, generally, can be any function, $\theta$ is the parameters of the neural network, and consequently, $P(D|\theta)$ is defined by the neural network (let's say a CNN), and $D$ is my dataset. I define $P(\theta)$ to be a gaussian with a fixed variance, but in general it can be anything really.

Since we're talking about a deep neural network, this is not easy to compute even with MCMC. So, one possibility I could think of for estimating this value is to try to estimate the sums in both the nominator and the denominator with as many large terms in them as possible: Basically, assuming $P(D,\theta)=P(D|\theta)P(\theta)$ takes either very large values or very small values, I train the network with SGD on my data $D$ to maximize the objective function $P(D,\theta)$, and repeat this $N$ times. Each of those $N$ times, SGD lands on a different set of parameters $\theta_i$ for $1\leq i\leq N$.

If we can assume (☆) the probability of landing on $\theta_i$ is proportional to $P(D,\theta_i)$, then the following would be the estimate of the desired value:
$$\frac{\sum_i f(\theta_i)}{N}$$
The idea here is basically to directly sample from the posterior, which is usually done via more popular sampling methods such as MCMC, but here, because it would take a long time due to the dimensionality of the neural network, I do it with another "sampling" algorithm (i.e. multiple runs of SGD).

But since I am not sure of that assumption (☆), instead I assume in the region of the parameter space where $P(D,\theta)$ is large, SGD can land on any parameters with the same probability. So, I use the following as my estimate.
$$\frac{\sum_i P(D,\theta_i)f(\theta_i)}{\sum_i P(D,\theta_i)}$$

How good or bad is this estimation? Is there an upper bound or lower bound on its error? Also, is there a better way for doing this that can work on neural networks in the order of tens of thousands of parameters? I feel like this problem must be popular enough to have better solutions but I am not even sure where to look.